# Regarding Joins of tables: relate uid and gid?

Tags: php, sql

```
********      * *********
              *  GROUPS
                 -------------    
users         *  uid(Primary KEy)
                 gname        
------        *  gdesc
uid            *
username        * 
password         * 
FULL_NAME         *
date_of_birth     * 
phone_number      *
valid            *
manu_gps
editor_map
operator
gid (Foreign Key) reference to GROUPS(uid)
```

Can you help with SQL query. I should join this tables . In other words, i should put relate gid and uid and instead of gid pun appropriate gname

Comment: kindly reformat your table and their key properly .
I think in Group Table you have `gid` as primary key and may be it's typo here that you typed `uid` in Group table.

Comment: nope it is not a typo. uid is a primary key in a group table

Comment: By typo means ... its naming convesion typo.. BTW yep everyone free to use name key as you want.

Because users and groups both having uid key which i think create the confusion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT u.uid,
       u.username,
       g.uid,
       g.gname
       FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN groups g
                      ON g.uid = u.gid;
```